# How to Round Up Using Static Cast and for Homework Assignment

Tags: c++

I have been working on my homework assignment for school for a number of hours and can't get the correct output. I don't really understand the issue. But it has something to do with casting or it not rounding up properly. It is a height conversation assignment for cm to feet/ inches. Seems simple but can't seem to ever get it to work. What am I missing?

- Also you can't use the rounding function. You can only add 0.5 for the exercise.

Here is my code thus far:

```
// Height conversion assignment from cm to feet and inches


#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


const float CM_TO_INCHES = 2.54;
const int INCHES_TO_FEET = 12;

int main()
{
    
    int cm, inches, feet, inchesRemainder;
    
    cout << "Enter the height in centimeters: ";
    cin >> cm;
    
   
    inches = cm / CM_TO_INCHES;
    
    
    feet = inches / INCHES_TO_FEET;
    inchesRemainder = inches % INCHES_TO_FEET;
    
    cout << cm << " cm(s) = ";
    
    
    cout << static_cast <int> (feet + 0.5) << " foot (feet) and ";
    cout << static_cast <int> (inchesRemainder + 0.5) << " inch(es) " << endl;
    

    return 0;
}
```

Expected Ouput:

Run 1
Enter the height in centimeter(s) -- 182
182 centimeter(s) = 6 foot/feet and 0 inche(s)

Run 2
Enter the height in centimeter(s) -- 165
165 centimeter(s) = 5 foot/feet and 5 inche(s)

Run 3
Enter the height in centimeter(s) -- 140
140 centimeter(s) = 4 foot/feet and 7 inche(s)

Actual Output:

Run 1
Enter the height in centimeter(s) -- 182
182 centimeter(s) = 5 foot/feet and 11 inche(s)

Run 2
Enter the height in centimeter(s) -- 165
165 centimeter(s) = 5 foot/feet and 4 inche(s)

Run 3
Enter the height in centimeter(s) -- 140
140 centimeter(s) = 4 foot/feet and 7 inche(s)

Comment: What input do you give?  What is the output you get, and what is the output that you expect?

Comment: *What am I missing?* -- Giving us the input data.

Comment: You have declared `*int* cm, inches, feet, inchesRemainder`. This leads to integer division. Instead, declare all these variables as *double*. That is, `double cm, inches, feet, inchesRemainder`. Idk if there's sth else wrong but this is certainly one big problem.

Comment: You only have `int` variables. All your operations will be lossy.

Comment: *Also you can't use the rounding function. You can only add 0.5 for the exercise.* -- There is a lot more sophistication in the `std::round()` function than merely adding 0.5.  Once you change your variables to `float`, there could still be values where you will not get the correct result after adding 0.5.

Comment: @RonaldSouza Using double won't make the modulus operator work

Comment: Changing the declared values to double repaired one of the issues. Feet is now calculated correctly. But the remainder will no longer calculate.  It says 'double won't calculate with a const integer'. What is the best way to calculate the remainder for inches left without it becoming lossly. I think this is the issue.

Comment: @CésarDebeunne You can still use the `fmod` function.

Comment: @HeronFree If `feet` is the correct integral number of feet, then `inchesRemainder = inches - (feet * INCHES_TO_FEET);`

Comment: @HeronFree -- You are lucky that `cm` is an integer.  If the user were allowed to enter fractional values for `cm`, expect the scenario I mentioned previously to show up.

Comment: Your (now deleted) explanation on what the 0.5 does is a bit off. 4.8 + 0.5 = 5.3, which *can* be implicitly converted back to in `int` (depends on what you do), at which point it gets truncated and just become 5. It's extremely important to not gloss over things in programming. It's how most mistakes happen.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I got it to work with all your help. And some help from a forth year. Unfortunately, I can't post the final results and it's an official assignment, others are also completing. But I'm back on track. Welcome to first year computer science.

Answer (score 1):

A short code review:

```cpp
// Height conversion assignment from cm to feet and inches


#include <iostream>

using namespace std;  // Bad practice; stop using sooner than later

// Prefer double; it's the 'default' floating point type.
// These constants don't need to be global. Get out of that practice
// sooner than later.
const float CM_TO_INCHES = 2.54;  // Names would make more sense as units
const int INCHES_TO_FEET = 12;

int main()
{
    
    int cm, inches, feet, inchesRemainder;  // Prefer declaring variables when needed
                                            // and one at a time.
    
    cout << "Enter the height in centimeters: ";
    cin >> cm;
    
    // Currently doing a cast and truncation already.
    // Because you're not controlling the process, your results
    // are unexpected.
    inches = cm / CM_TO_INCHES;  // This is where you need to 'round.'
    
    
    feet = inches / INCHES_TO_FEET;
    inchesRemainder = inches % INCHES_TO_FEET;
    
    cout << cm << " cm(s) = ";  // No need for (s); that's not how units work
    
    // These casts are useless; your variables are already ints
    cout << static_cast <int> (feet + 0.5) << " foot (feet) and ";
    cout << static_cast <int> (inchesRemainder + 0.5) << " inch(es) " << endl;
    

    return 0;
}
```

You need to "round" and cast only as part of your initial conversion calculation. It's really just a truncation, which is why you're adding the 0.5.

`int inches = static_cast<int>((cm / CM_PER_INCH) + 0.5);` will get you the correct number of inches, and your other calcluations can simply use integers. No further casting is required. I have an extra `( )` in my cast, but meh. C++ does follow the order of operations that you're used to for arithmetic. That `static_cast<>()` is also not needed, but being explicit shows yourself and other programmers what your intent is, i.e., you're showing that the implicit cast is desired.

I changed the name of the constant to an actual unit because that's what it is. Conversion factors, text and all, are actual units that you manipulate in tandem with the numbers. In my solution, I just used the typical x' y" notation for feet and inches, as it's cleaner and doesn't require any branching or double notations.